# Include headers in URL

Tags: http, web, header, powerbi

I have an url which allow to download a file such as:

https://mysystem.department.company/u/userid/projectid/raw/fileid/filename.csv?inline=false

Due to various aberrations at my company, I need to add the below header fields directly into the url (because PowerBI server does not recognize the headers that were added locally in Web Connections).

Is there any way to add the headers 'X-API-KEY'= 'XXX123' directly to the URL? I've tried
https://mysystem.department.company/u/userid/projectid/raw/fileid/filename.csv?inline=false&X-API-KEY=XXX123 without success.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

No. URL and request header fields are separate things.

Comment: could you please elaborate? where can i find docs on what headers are, and what executes them?

Comment: for example the `query` part can be included in the url after `?`, whats the difference with headers?

Comment: URIs are defined RFC 3986. HTTP is defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 7231. The HTTP request URI is simply different from header fields. Nobody "executes" headers. And how they are treated precisely is really up to the server you send them to.